# How to store database in to array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, store

I need to store value in column name "thasaurus" into array name "doc[i]"[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtK4i.png)

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: please don't use picture with your code because someone want to try to your code it isn't useful for us ,thanks

Comment: $sql = "SELECT id, thasaurus FROM product";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$doc= array();
$i=1;
//if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     //$Str1=mysqli_num_rows($result);
     $doc[] = $row[ 'thasaurus' ];
       //echo $doc[$i];
      $i++;
  
   
} 
 echo $doc[$i];
echo "<br>";

Comment: Please initialize `$i=0;` as `$doc[]` array will always start with zero.

Comment: @Atif it does not matter if `$i` is used or not. the value of `$row['thasaurus']` will automatically be inserted into `$doc` in order 0, 1, 2, 3....., regardless of the value of $i

Comment: @เชอรี่พิ้งค์ชมพู๊ชมพู simply use print_r($doc); to see the result. If your query is not returning empty result set, then print_r($doc) will give you something to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an array into JSON using json_encode for inserting it into DB and at the time of retrieval you can use json_decode for use.

Comment: If your array is not associative you can also use explode and implode to convert array into string and vice versa.

Comment: The good news is [MySQL 5.7 supports JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). I think you're on the right track here. If you could improve your answer with a bit of code that'd make it the right answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql1="SELECT id,thasaurus  FROM  `product`";
$res1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$doc=array();
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
 {
   $doc[]=$row1['thasaurus'];
 }
 var_dump($doc);//to check the values in that variable
```

if you want to echo that variable use foreach

```
foreach($doc as $document)
 {
  echo $document."<br>"
 }
```

or by for loop you can extract that values

```
for($i=0;$i<count($doc);$i++)
{  
  echo $doc[$i];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
<?php   
$sql = "SELECT id, thasaurus FROM product"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

$doc= array(); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
     // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
      { 
        $doc[] = $row['thasaurus'];
      } 
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($doc);
?>
```

Comment: `$i` is irrelevant in the current context. You are using `$i=0` to create an associative array with index starting from 0. This would not be necessary. Simply using `$doc[]=$row['thasaurus'];` will do the same.